# How does Instagram embed clickable text in stories?

Tags: android

I'm trying to Implement Instagram like stories feature in My Android App. I can make Text Overlay on Images but How do I make them Clickable as in the above Screenshot?

[image: ScreenShot]

Thanks

Comment: setOnClickListner on the textview.

Comment: how did you manage to overlay the text at different angles?

Comment: @ReyanshMishra Do you got any solution ? Can you please help me

Answer (score 1):

Try using `clickable span` with `SpannableString` like this

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview01);      
SpannableString span = new SpannableString("test link span");   
span.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {  
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {  

   Log.d("main", "Now clicked");

} }, 0, span.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

 tv .setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
 tv.setText(span);
```

Also along with this you can set `UnderlineSpan` , `ForegroundColorSpan` etc etc, to set custom text to your textView !!

You can **read** [this article](http://androidcocktail.blogspot.in/2014/03/android-spannablestring-example.html)