# How to set part of TextView clickable while hiding the link?

Tags: java, android, textview, spannable

I have a TextView to show recipients of emails, the original string will be something like `"FirstName LastName <xx@yy.com>, FirstName LastName <xx@yy.com>, FirstName LastName <xx@yy.com>"`. I want to show a string like `"FirstName LastName, FirstName LastName, FirstName LastName"` while `FirstName LastName` is clickable. I know how to get `FirstName LastName` and I know how to make `xx@yy.com` clickable by using `URLSpan`, but it only makes the `xx@yy.com` clickable, what I want to do is to only show `FirstName LastName` and make it clickable, any idea?

Comment: Use `ClickableSpan`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49382532/how-does-instagram-embed-clickable-text-in-stories/49382706#49382706

Comment: The problem is that I need to hide part of the text, I know how to set the clickable but how to hide the other part of the text?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by extending the ClickableSpan and pass in the hidden information, like the code below.

```
public class RecipientsSpan extends ClickableSpan {
    public String name;
    private String emailAddress;
    private int textColor;

    private RecipientsClickHandler recipientsClickHandler;

    public RecipientsSpan(String name, String emailAddress, int textColor) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
        this.textColor = textColor;
    }

    /**
     * Set the interface that will be used to handle the click event.
     * @param recipientsClickHandler interface to pass in.
     */
    public void setRecipientsClickHandler(@NonNull RecipientsClickHandler recipientsClickHandler) {
        this.recipientsClickHandler = recipientsClickHandler;
    }

    /**
     * Interface to handle click event for different spans inside the same TextView.
     */
    public interface RecipientsClickHandler {
        void onRecipientsClicked(@NonNull String name, @NonNull String emailAddress);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (recipientsClickHandler != null) {
            recipientsClickHandler.onRecipientsClicked(name, emailAddress);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Make text show the color specified and also avoid the default underline.
     * @param ds TextPaint that will be applied to the text.
     */
    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(@NonNull TextPaint ds) {
        ds.setColor(textColor);
        ds.setUnderlineText(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For each TextView you can set an onClick listener inside your Java code.
So with that you can easily link the TextView with the mailadress

Comment: There is just one textview, not multiple of them.

Comment: Then do it like proposed here https://stackoverflow.com/q/10696986/4417786

Comment: The biggest problem is that I need to hide some text while making other text clickable.

Comment: There are enough methods and ways to alter strings! So you don't hide the text, you delete it

Comment: How do I know which email I clicked then? Do you have any reference that I can follow? Thanks!

Comment: You make it like proposed in the link above. For each name and mail combination you remove the mail from the string and set it as the listener for the clickableSpan. So you got a span for each name!

Comment: It ended that I need to create a new class that extends ClickableSpan and handle the click event there.